# Quiero leer lineas de un archivo y no me funciona JAVA

Tags: java, bucles

Muy buenas chicos/as! Estoy intentando leer lineas de un tipo ".txt" aun que lo tengo en .test, es lo mismo .
Lo que tengo que hacer es leer las 6 primeras líneas, y después que me lea las líneas una por una (cada vez que meto ENTER me pasa a la siguiente línea) hasta que no haya más.

Este es mi código del main, lo pongo recortado porque solo hace falta ver donde lo ejecuto:

public class Main {

```
private void printMenu(String p) { //String per imprimir els menus dels tests
    System.out.println("Has triat " + p);
    System.out.println("Selecciona el test que vols fer");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(" 1 - Dificultat baixa");
    System.out.println(" 2 - Dificultat normal");
    System.out.println(" 3 - Dificultat alta");
}


private void run() {
    LT lt = new LT();
    char lletra = ' ';
    int real = ' ';
    String Nom; //String on es guarda el nom
    System.out.println("Benvingut a la pràctica de tests");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Quin és el teu nom?");
    Nom = lt.llegirLinia(); //Lletgeix l'escrit per teclat i ho guarda al string
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Benvingut " + Nom); //PROVA

    while (lletra != 'd' && lletra != 'D') { //Feim un while per triar opció

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Selecciona una de les opcions següents:");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("'A' ---> Tests disponibles");
        System.out.println("'B' ---> Tutorial");
        System.out.println("'C' ---> Historial de partides");
        System.out.println("'D' ---> Sortir del programa");
        System.out.println("");

        lletra = lt.llegirCaracter();
        switch (lletra) { //El switch el cream per poder fer diferentes opcions                

            case 'A': //Opció per jugar
            case 'a':
                System.out.println("Tests disponibles");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Selecciona el tema del text: ");
                System.out.println("'N' - Naturalesa ");
                System.out.println("'A' - Animals ");
                System.out.println("'V' - Videojocs ");
                System.out.println("'C' - Cotxes ");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Per tornar al menú prinicpal tecletja T");

                while (lletra != 't' && lletra != 'D') { //Triam el temari dels tests
                    lletra = lt.llegirCaracter();

                    switch (lletra) {

                        case 'N':
                        case 'n':
                            printMenu("Naturalesa");
                            real = lt.llegirSencer();
                            switch (real) {
                                case 1: {
                                    try {
                                        Lectura lr = new Lectura("Naturalesa/4.test");

                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                                case 2:
                                    System.out.println("Naturalesa/5.test");
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    System.out.println("Naturalesa/6.test");
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'A':
                        case 'a':
                            printMenu("Animals");
                            break;

                        case 'V':
                        case 'v':
                            printMenu("Videojocs");
                            break;

                        case 'C':
                        case 'c':
                            printMenu("Cotxes");
                            break;

                        default: //Error que surt si l'usuari introdueix una lletra incorrecte
                            System.out.println("Opción no váilda");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 'B': //Opció per sebrer com es juga 'Tutorial'
            case 'b':
                System.out.println("Tutorial");
                Tutorial.alTutorial();
                break;

            case 'C': //Opció per vorer l'historial de les darreres partides
            case 'c':
                System.out.println("Historial de partides");
                break;

            case 'D': //Opció per sortir del programa
            case 'd':
                System.out.println("Sortir del programa");
                break;

            default: //Error que surt si l'usuari introdueix una lletra incorrecte
                System.out.println("Opción no váilda");
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Y aquí la clase que utilizo para leer:

public class Lectura {

```
FileReader fr;
BufferedReader bf;

public Lectura (String FitxerLletgit) throws IOException {
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(FitxerLletgit); //Agafam el FitxerLletgit amb el FileReader
        bf = new BufferedReader(fr); //Agafam el "fr" que té el fitxer i el guardam al "bf"
       //System.out.println(bf.readLine());
        while ((bf.readLine()) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
               String st;
               st = bf.readLine();
               System.out.println(st); 
            }   
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }       
}
```

}

Aquí le estoy poniendo un for de longitud tres, he probado con el .lenght del string que utilizo para meter el archivo pero tampoco.
No se donde reside el problema, supongo que en la clase de leer, pero no se cual, he probado mirando videos de youtube pero ninguno me ayuda o no lo entiendo.

PD: Está en catalan, si teneis dificultad para leerlo puedo cambiar el lenguaje

Comment: El ciclo for es innecesario, la lectura ya se está realizando en la condición del while pero se está perdiendo el contenido de la línea debido a que no se está almacenando en una variable para su posterior uso.
Es decir, la función `readLine()` retorna la línea actual y avanza a la siguiente.

Answer (score 1):

El problema ocurre al llamar la función `readLine()`, está función retorna la línea actual, y aumenta la posición de línea actual para la siguiente iteración. Al llamarla tantas veces, el lector se desplaza más de lo que esperas.
Es decir, no hace falta el ciclo for, pero si es necesario salvar la línea de texto en una variable cuando llamas a `readLine()`.
A continuación te doy un ejemplo que únicamente lee y escribe la cantidad de líneas especificadas, para un archivo dado por una ruta de acceso.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        writeFileLines("archivo.test", 6);
    }

    /**
     * Escribe las primeras N líneas de texto de un archivo.
     *
     * @param path  Ruta de acceso al archivo.
     * @param count Cantidad de líneas a obtener.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void writeFileLines(String path, int count) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);                        // almacena en memoria el archivo a leer.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));     // buffer de lectura.

        String tmpLine;     // almacenará temporalmente las líneas de texto.

        // ciclo de lectura: leerá solo si existen líneas para leer y la cantidad de líneas pendientes es mayor a cero.
        while ((tmpLine = br.readLine()) != null && 0 < count) {
            System.out.println(tmpLine);    // escribe la línea de texto actual.
            count--;                        // reduce el contador de líneas de texto pendientes.
        }

        br.close();     // cierra para liberar recursos.
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Miguel, me ha sido de gran ayuda! Lo has explicado muy claramente, lo he probado y va genial. Voy a probar con el siguiente paso!